# Why isn't a variable recognised within my _show.html file?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-injection

So I have a calendar controller and a view called _show.html.erb (it's a partial which is loaded into a bigger view). I'm trying to use an attribute 'starts_at' which belongs to an 'event' model object, but my html highlights it saying "cannot find starts_at".

If I try and load my main page it gives the error:

NoMethodError in Pages#main

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Here is the calendar controller with my show method:

```
class CalendarsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @calendar = Calendar.new(calendar_params)

  end

  def create
    @calendar = Calendar.new(calendar_params)
  end

private
  def calendar_params
    params.require(:customer_id)
  end


  def show
    @calendar = current_customer.calendar
    @events = @calendar.events

  end

end
```

My events controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :logged_in?


  def new
    @event = Event.new
    @calendar = current_customer.calendar

  end


  def create

    @calendar = current_customer.calendar

    @event = @calendar.events.build(event_params)

    if @event.save
      redirect_to '/main' #'/main/#{@calendar.id}'
    else
      redirect_to '/compose'
      end

  end
```

Here is the _show.html.erb snippet:

```
<td id = "mon900" class ="freeslot" width=75 valign=top>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
                normal'>&nbsp;</p>
        <% @events.each do |e|%>
        <p><%= e.starts_at %></p> <!-- It wont pick up starts_at-->
        <% end %>
 </td>
```

Here is the code where I am rendering this partial. It is being rendered in main.html.erb which belongs to my Pages controller:

```
<%= render partial: '/calendars/show', locals: {} %>
```

Pages controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  #before_action :require_customer, only: [:main]

  def home

  end


  def main

  end

end
```

Just for clarity, here are my calendar and event models:

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar

end
```

The :starts_at attribute of an event is of datetime type. When I was learning how to do ruby on rails (admittedly not long ago) I was told this sort of ruby injection would work. What is the problem here? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by It wont pick up? Do you get nil value? error?

Comment: it highlights it saying "cant find starts_at"

Comment: Please update your question with full error message.

Comment: I have done that now

Comment: That is not the full error message

Comment: ok I am getting an error on the line before - I have updated it with full error message

Comment: Show the code of rendering that partial.

Comment: ok I have done that now

Comment: Ok. now in which view file you are rendering that partial?

Comment: it is rendered in my Pages controller's main.html.erb file

Comment: Hmm. I need to see the pages_controller main action. Could you post it please?

Comment: ok but my main action is empty

Comment: Hmm. That's the problem. You should be having `@events` defined in main action and you should be passing it as locals to the partial.

Comment: There's your problem. You're trying to use a variable that doesn't exist in that controller's action...

Comment: could you write a full answer on how I can fix it? I am very new to ruby/rails and don't have much confidence in the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need some validation that the user exists so something like this should work:

```
#controllers/pages
def main
    @events = current_user ? current_user.calendar.events : []
end
```

Clarification; this is the above ternary operation written out:

```
if current_user
    @events = current_user.calendar.events
else
    @events = [] # an empty array, which will address "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"
end
```

This way if there is no user logged in it will return an empty array of "events". You could just as easily replace the array with a [scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope) of actual events, such as:

```
@events = current_user ? current_user.calendar.events : Event.all
```

Comment: ok, could you please explain to me what the " : [] " is for at the end?

Comment: sure thing @Sarahshuffle, I've edited the answer to clarify.